# How can I achieve indoor mapping in Android application?

Tags: android, indoor-positioning-system, google-geolocation, google-indoor-maps

I have floor plans for my building and I want to track where user is moving along with the floor details, Can anyone suggest what will be useful for it? or where can I register indoor mapping details in map?

Also I want to see path for a particular user's movement.

**Any third party library suggestions or help me with google map indoor mapping feature.**